# I'd like to know all of these mean the same without changing meaning. -

Tags: sentence-construction

I'd like to know all of these mean the same without changing meaning.

> 1. I didn't design it in the way you'd asked us to.
> 2. I designed it in a different way from the way you'd asked us to.
> 3. I designed it differently than you'd asked us to.
> 4. The way you'd asked us to design it is different from the way we actually did.

Answer (score 2):

Except for number 4 being *we* instead of *I*, yes, they basically mean the same thing.

Comment: Right.  But I would spell out "you had" rather than using the contraction "you'd". I don't know why. Or you could shorten it to "you", putting it all in simple past tense.